# sqlcmd backup script failing

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use a simple batch script to backup a local instance of SQL Express 2012, as follows:

```
@echo off
SET BACKUP_DIR=E:\BackupData
SET SERVER=.\\sqlexpress
set dom=%date:~0,2%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set year=%date:~6,4%
set file=%year%-%month%-%dom%
sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d master -Q "exec sp_msforeachdb 'BACKUP DATABASE [?] TO DISK=''%BACKUP_DIR%\?.Full.%file%.bak'''
```

The script is failing to run with the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Client unable
>   to establish connection due to prelogin failure.

This is on Server 2008 R2, my SQL database (on localhost) instance is named `SQLEXPRESS`. There is an instance of SQL Express 2008 on the system (hence client 10.0).

The database is configured to use a trusted connection, and the .net desktop software deployed on our network PCs is able to access the database without any problem.

Am I missing something obvious here, I've done a fair amount of searching for this error message, and haven't found anything that has been particularly useful so far.

Comment: Databases are not configured to use trusted connections, applications are configured to connect to databases with trusted connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change remove one of the slashes in `SET SERVER=.\\sqlexpress`. It should be `SET SERVER=.\sqlexpress`

Comment: Thanks, that and the closing double quotes around the query were missing.